# Mongo-Connector not sending data to Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I want to link Elasticsearch with my local MongoDB

Here are my `mongoconnector.json` configs

```
{
   "oplogFile": "/usr/local/etc/oplog.timestamp",
   "noDump": false,
   "batchSize": 500,
   "verbosity": 2,
   "continueOnError": false,
   "logging": {
       "type": "stream"
   },
   "docManagers": [
       {
           "docManager": "elastic2_doc_manager",
           "targetURL": "127.0.0.1:9200",
           "bulkSize": 10,
           "uniqueKey": "_id",
           "args": {
              "clientOptions": {"timeout": 5000}
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

and the command

```
mongo-connector -m "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/MyDatabase?replicaSet=rs0" -c ./mongoconnector.json
```

The first time i've run the query, i got POST logs, meaning this was working

```
2021-04-30 21:12:59,677 [INFO] elasticsearch:83 - POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk [status:200 request:0.062s]
2021-04-30 21:12:59,705 [INFO] elasticsearch:83 - POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk [status:200 request:0.028s]
2021-04-30 21:12:59,736 [INFO] elasticsearch:83 - POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk [status:200 request:0.030s]
2021-04-30 21:12:59,776 [INFO] elasticsearch:83 - POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk [status:200 request:0.038s]
2021-04-30 21:12:59,820 [INFO] elasticsearch:83 - POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk [status:200 request:0.043s]
2021-04-30 21:12:59,861 [INFO] elasticsearch:83 - POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk [status:200 request:0.040s]
```

Then I stopped the process to fix something in my MongoDB and deleted elasticsearch indexes manually.

Now when I run the same command I get these logs

```
2021-04-30 22:10:03,572 [INFO] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:78 - OplogThread for replica set 'rs0' is up to date with the oplog.
2021-04-30 22:10:33,577 [INFO] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:78 - OplogThread for replica set 'rs0' is up to date with the oplog.
2021-04-30 22:11:03,583 [INFO] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:78 - OplogThread for replica set 'rs0' is up to date with the oplog.
2021-04-30 22:11:33,588 [INFO] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:78 - OplogThread for replica set 'rs0' is up to date with the oplog.
2021-04-30 22:12:03,594 [INFO] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:78 - OplogThread for replica set 'rs0' is up to date with the oplog.
2021-04-30 22:12:33,597 [INFO] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:78 - OplogThread for replica set 'rs0' is up to date with the oplog.
```

... and no data is inserted in elasticsearch

Is there a way to force erasing/inserting data in elasticsearch ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it, juste delete /usr/local/etc/oplog.timestamp